# NetBeans wrong output for acos(-1)

Tags: c++, netbeans, pi, long-double

I had an assignment that dealt with calculating pi by a few different iterative methods and comparing it with the value calculated by `pi = acos(static_cast<long double>(-1.0))` (storing as a long double). For some reason, NetBeans gives me `-8.8796093704934495e+043`. From my limited knowledge, it seems like there is a signed/unsigned disagreement somewhere. I've set the compiler to use the C++11 standards. What am I missing?

Comment: `acos()` accepts `double` as its parameter. Why do you cast the _parameter_ into `long double`?

Comment: Can you show us a short complete example?  Not failing in Visual Studio or here: http://ideone.com/UKbUm8

Comment: Here's the complete code: http://pastebin.com/RTdaGxF6
@timrau, I'm casting it into `long double` because that's how the instructor did it. Yes, it works fine in Visual Studio, which is what I tend to use because it's less problematic.